# Changing ROM in Dell Venue 7 Wifi

Tags: cyanogenmod, root-access, custom-roms

I have a Dell Venue 7 (only Wifi) which is a piece of crap - too many bugs and Dell has stopped supporting it. Is there a way to put Cyanogen or anything else on it?

Comment: Intel-based devices almost never get custom ROMs - ZenFone 2 is the only notable exception due to popularity.

Comment: OP - there's not even a custom recovery available for the tablet for the reason above, so you won't even be able to flash _anything_. If you don't want to give it up, start by learning to port that. Then again, since support for the device has already halted, you might not even have the resource for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can root *Dell Venue 7* and put some custom roms on it (if there are any). But I think, best you can do is root the phone and play with it.

**Root:**

1. **Download One Click Root**. Install One Click Root onto your PC or Mac.
2. **Connect your device to computer** by a standard USB cable.
3. **Enable USB Debugging**.
4. **Run one click root**.

**Custom Roms with custom recoveries: (Read *EDIT* below)**

*Note: Sadly it is a Intel-based phone with less popularity, it doesn't have enough research or tools provided by developers to try out cool roms.*

Here is the link to custom roms & recoveries for venue, you can try them

(*I've doubt if they will work for Venue 7*):

http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/Dell_Venue/ROMs

***EDIT: Pointed out by Andy Yan, that custom roms provided in above links are for the original Venue (phone) released back in the days of Android 2.2***

Comment: Why do you feel they won't work?

Comment: Is there a reason why Intel based devices don't have too many options with custom ROMs?

Comment: Just edit out the "custom ROM" part - those are for the original Venue (phone) released back in the days of Android 2.2. OP, root is best you can get if feasible.

Comment: @user93353 Processor architecture (you need to rely on Intel-provided sources to even build one, and Intel stopped support quite early), and of course popularity.

Comment: Is there a point in rooting without putting a custom ROM?

Comment: I totally agree with Andy...and you can do many other things with root access, custom ROMs is just one of those. You can hack into games, play with internal and external softwares and many other interesting stuff. A rooted device is more interesting than a normal non-rooted device. That's a universal truth.

Comment: @9gager - this tablet is very buggy - for e.g. facebook crashes every 5 minutes. Dell has stopped supporting it - is there any way root access will help fix this?